# Why have #md5=... in the URL anchor?

Tags: url, download, md5, anchor

Some download links contain a md5 value in the URL anchor, [for instance](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#easy-install):

```
http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.1.tar.gz#md5=e6224b1da4636dd8ae53407fc67bb35b
```

What is the intent behind this convention? Are there download tools or HTTP clients that make use of this encoded md5 value?

`wget` or `curl` does not seem to use it:

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.1.tar.gz#md5=e6224b1da4636dd8ae53407fc67bb353
[...]
Saving to: `distribute-0.6.1.tar.gz'
[...]

$ ls -a
.  ..  distribute-0.6.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Good question; I was wondering about that, too

Answer (score 3):

That is for your own independent verification purposes.

Adding it as an anchor allows it to be ignored as part of the URL, while still providing it as part of the link.

Also, the convention is welcoming to third party apps that may hash the file, though I do not know of any that actually do.

Comment: I *vaguely* remember some command like tool actually saving the md5 (in URL anchor) in a separate file. Both wget and curl doesn't seem to save any other file though.